# How to append the version of dependencies to filenames when `bower install`

Tags: javascript, version, bower

When I use `bower install` to install the dependencies, they will be downloaded into `bower_components`, like:

```
├── jquery
│   ├── AUTHORS.txt
│   ├── CONTRIBUTING.md
│   ├── MIT-LICENSE.txt
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── build
│   │   ├── release-notes.js
│   │   ├── release-notes.txt
│   │   └── release.js
│   ├── component.json
│   ├── composer.json
│   ├── grunt.js
│   ├── jquery.js
│   ├── jquery.min.js
│   ├── package.json
```

You can see there is no version in the file names.

Is there any way to make bower add the versions to the file name or path automatically, so that I don't need to worry about the browser-cache if I include them directly in the web server?

I want it like this:

```
├── jquery-1.9.1
│        ├── AUTHORS.txt
│        ├── CONTRIBUTING.md
│        ├── MIT-LICENSE.txt
│        ├── README.md
│        ├── build
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this :

`bower install jquery-1.9.1=jquery#1.9.1`